# Deleting an uploaded file from the server in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I am trying to upload files to a folder from the admin side like a CMS.
The front-end will display links to download the file.
On the admin end, I would like to not only delete the reference to but also remove the actual file from the server.

Here is the part of my controller that saves the uploaded file:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        ViewBag.fileName = fileName.ToString();

        return RedirectToAction("Create", new {fileName = fileName });
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In the `Create` view, the admin is then allowed to enter other details about the document and that is stored on a table along with the fileName.

Now I need to be able to link to that document name like `document.pdf`. Am I even able to link to an uploads folder under `App_Data` folder?

Also, how do I remove the file and not just the table row on doing delete?

Comment: I ended up doing this for PDF and it "worked" but wondering if I need to worry about any memory issues etc or does FileStreamResults handle everything?
`public ActionResult Document(string fileName) { try { var fn = fileName; var fpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fn); return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(fpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "application/pdf"); } ...`

Comment: it depends how much traffic your web app encounters. How many users do you have?

Comment: @Alex Mostly internal staff use.  Basically not much traffic.  BUT if I were to create something more public, do you have any pointers to a best practice info?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I would still prefer my answer if it were to go public; with the exception that the file paths should have a Guid in them so that no two requests will generate the same path. Also, the validity of the file path expires over time. So basically, there must be more security involved in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate controller to handle the downloading of the file. It also prevents your users to hotlink directly to the files.

```
public ActionResult GetDocument(String pathName)
{
    try
    {
        Byte[] buffer = DownloadMyFileFromSomeWhere(pathName);
        FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(buffer, "PDF"); // or whatever file ext
        // these next two lines are optional
        String[] folders = pathName.Split(new char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);            
        result.FileDownloadName = folders[folders.Length - 1];

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log the error or something
    }
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

Where `DownloadMyFileFromSomeWhere(string)` should be able to retrieve the byte-array file from some storage like a blob or even the local server. It can look something like:

```
private Byte[] DownloadMyFileFromSomeWhere(string pathname)
{
    Byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(pathname));
    return file;
}
```

For the Admin side, you can do the same approach: Write a separate controller to delete the file and its entry in the database.

Comment: Could you elaborate a litte more on what DownloadMyFileFromSomeWhere() might look like or have a reference to another article.  Thanks,

Comment: @Joe, it could be a simple fetch to a local file in your webserver or a download from a blob or cloud. Start with looking at `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` for example.

Comment: I added a DownloadMyFileFromSomeWhere method to your answer.

Comment: @Joe, Please note that `pathName` from the controller action is different from the `DownloadMyFileFromSomeWhere` parameter. One is being sent via the request, while the other is a system path, which should be private and relative to the server. Frankly, the implementation of that method is not really relevant. But for illustration's sake, thank you for pointing it out and let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- If you have rights to save a file somewhere, you should also have the rights to delete it.  You can use normal file operations to do this.
- IIS *should* block you from linking to a file under App_Data.  You have a couple of options:

  - Create an action that reads the file from that location and streams it back to the browser
  - Store in a different location - somewhere that the user will actually have access to.

The benefit of the first option is that you can easily add authentication, etc. to your action to secure access to the files, whereas the second option would require you to add a web.config in the folder with the appropriate roles and access rights.  However, on the other hand, you'll have to supply appropriate headers in your action method so the browser knows what to do with the file, rather than letting IIS figure it out for you.